# Visualize H2o XGBoost tree in json format, can not find the missing child

Tags: xgboost, h2o

I am trying to visualize my H2O XGBoost model in JSON format using below command:
`java -cp h2o-genmodel.jar hex.genmodel.tools.PrintMojo -i XGBoost_model_R_1597776279050_3.zip --tree 1 --format json`

The above command output the tree structure in JSON format like below:

```
"rightChild": {
      "nodeNumber": 2,
      "weight": 0.0,
      "colId": 382,
      "colName": "var_2",
      "leftward": false,
      "isCategorical": false,
      "inclusiveNa": false,
      "splitValue": 0.195,
      "rightChild": {
        "nodeNumber": 6,
        "weight": 0.0,
        "colId": 340,
        "colName": "var_6",
        "leftward": false,
        "isCategorical": false,
        "inclusiveNa": true,
        "splitValue": 1.0,
        "rightChild": {
          "nodeNumber": 10,
          "weight": 0.0,
          "predValue": 0.011794609
        },
        "leftChild": {
          "nodeNumber": 9,
          "weight": 0.0,
          "predValue": 0.011531689
        }
```

I am trying to understand how the missing child can be calculated using above JSON for each node. The same structure can be view in png format and the missing node for the node var_6 is coming as left child. Is there a way to figure out the missing node by looking at the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `leftward` attribute - it's the so-called "majority way", which means that all data records that can't be explicitly evaluated (eg. a data record with a missing value) will be sent there.

In the current case, `"leftward": false` should cause missing values to be sent to the right child node (node number 10).

Comment: In my model (XGBoost), all the nodes has leftward as false. Does that mean for missing values, it always goes to right node? I did some testing to print the tree path and I observed thats not the case. I am wondering if inclusiveNa also has something to do with missing nodes.

Comment: You should generate JSON printout in two ways - first using H2O tools, and then using XGBoost own tools. Perhaps the latter will be more informative/easier to interpret. Right now you have XGBoost model formatted according to H2O decision tree model "standards"; perhaps this representation is missing some crucial information.

Comment: I was able to use graphviz and dot format to see the missing node, I think json format to print mojo do not properly show the missing node for the nodes which has two terminal nodes.